# export mysql utf 8 data in excel

Tags: php

I'am trying to save mysql data in excel with UTF-8 encoding. But all data save in one cell.  but I have problem with Excel file. it shows the UTF-8 characters ugly.

Excel file:
[this is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXv13.png)

DB CONNECTION :

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("urulikanchan",$conn) or die("could not connect database");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
?>
```

EXCEL FILE DOWNLOAD:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <title>New Post</title>


</head>
<body>
<?php


include 'db.php';

$SQL = "SELECT  * from member_detail";
$header = '';
$result ='';
$exportData = mysql_query ($SQL ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $exportData );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $exportData , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $exportData ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $result .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );

if ( $result == "" )
{
    $result = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');

echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";


print "$header\n$result";

?>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Probably you know but: 
Must it be excel file? you can try to save on .csv file which is able to open in excel or open office, you can check in http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp or http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/

Comment: This isn't a native-format Excel file that you're generating, just a csv file with a tab separator (and a bad homebrew csv at that; at least try using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function, which will fix some of the potential problems

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a real excel file and not just CSV please consider using some PHP library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

Here is a simple code example that uses UTF characters:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Test UTF8 Characters:');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'éçà');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Export');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xlsx");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```